# How to indicate proportion of tasks in each of several sequential stages?

Tags: gui-design, progress-bar

I have many (thousands) of tasks, each currently in one of 5 sequential stages. (So every task goes through the exact same sequence, but concurrently, so that some are at a different stage from others). How should I indicate to the user the proportion of tasks in each stage? The simple answer would be a pie chart, but I don't know if there is a better option, given that the stages are sequential, and a pie chart doesn't convey any sort of sequence.

Comment: Why not try a stacked horizontal bar, with 5 stacks?  You can show the percentage of tasks that fall under each sequence, all totaling 100%.  The stacks can resize based on the number of tasks in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) layman's terms :

> "the simplest explanation is usually the correct one"

So, [**Pie Chart**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart) or even better, a **[Gauge Chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html)** is probably your best bet. If you need to have a sequence, then add them as a sequence, simple and to the point.

Undoubtedly, there are many other ways to do this, but in most cases, you don't need to complicate things unless there's an additional reason to do it. So, keep it simple, it works